# Child container with border-radius not taking parent height

Tags: html, sass

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/q2m7oLyr/) which tries to place a absolute positioned circle at the center of the parent. Somehow I have to give an extra pixel of padding in the child to cover the height of the parent container.

Is there a way to avoid this extra pixel.

```
padding: ($padding + 1); /*need to avoid this addition of 1 pixel*/
```

Any other suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: If you add `box-sizing: content-box;` to your centered element, this will make sure that padding and border-width are taking into account for the element's width and height.

Comment: @SaschaM78 did not work for me. Did you try it out in the fiddle?

Comment: Wrong interpretation from my side, I was looking at the horizontal, not vertical sizing. But I think I found the underlying problem as can be seen in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the font-size you define in your `.buttonContainer` class which will add a bit of extra padding around the contents. If you set a `line-height` of "24px", you can remove the additional pixel (in fact you would have needed 2px to have the same height) as can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/Ldo0uxk4/).

Here's your changed code:

```
.buttonContainer {
  /* ... */
  line-height: 24px;
  /* ... */
}

.buttonCounter {
  /* ... */
  padding: ($padding);
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and it does work but unfortunately, i need to now reduce the font size by 2px to align it in the middle vertically. I think I'll have to nest them in a container and to the alignment

Comment: @Saksham why not set `.buttonContainer { font-size: ($height); line-height: $height; }` in your code? No need to decrease the font size, just make sure these two are in sync. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/3vy657bs/1/) is another sample with changed height and colors to illustrate the sizing fits.

Comment: Yes did that. Thanks for your input.